# How to make jar file executable with nodejs in heroku

Tags: java, heroku, heroku-nodejs

I have a node application that executes a jar file as follows:

```
  command(params, cb) {
    var cmd = '/usr/bin/java -jar JavaAPI.jar ' + this.node_id + " " + this.node_address;
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        cmd += " " + params[i];
    }
    child = exec(cmd, cb);
}
```

Its working perfectly in local machine. Now I want to deploy it in git, I tried with pom.xml and java plugin as suggested in doc :
[java plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-executable-jar-files) and [with build packs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-grunt-with-java-and-maven-to-automate-javascript-tasks)
But none of these works. With build packs and pom.xml the following error occurs:

```
  Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) on project redditbot-mps: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class
```

This may be because i don't have java files. And with plugin no response.
What is the best way to deploy to heroku in my case ?
I just need to run a node project which depends on a .jar file for some results. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by, you want to deploy on git? Do you want to deploy on Heroku? What is the role of git here?

Comment: @Amolpskamble It was supposed to be heroku, my mistake, sorry :)